# openvino/ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable

Tags: python, dll, import, intel, openvino

I'm working with intel's openvino 2020.
I get this error I searched and tried a lot of solutions online, but It didn't work.
and honestly, I'm new to working with python, openvino. So I don't really understand the error.
this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_recognition_demo.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ie_module import InferenceContext
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2020.3.194\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\demos\python_demos\face_recognition_demo\ie_module.py", line 20, in <module>
    from openvino.inference_engine import IECore
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino\python\python3.6\openvino\inference_engine\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .ie_api import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

my imports:

```
import logging as log
import os.path as osp
import sys
import time
from argparse import ArgumentParser

import cv2
import numpy as np

from ie_module import InferenceContext
from landmarks_detector import LandmarksDetector
from face_detector import FaceDetector
from faces_database import FacesDatabase
from face_identifier import FaceIdentifier
```

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified your installation of OpenVINO by running the Image Classification Verification Script? Refer to the documentation from the link below and please verify your installation first since this error looks like a configuration mistake in the environment.
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2020.3/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html#Using-Demo-Scripts

Make sure to complete all steps given on the [Installation Guide for Windows](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2020.3/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html#installation_steps). Once verified done, then you can run the Interactive Face Recognition Demo. Here is the workaround to run the demo:

1. Setup OpenVINO environment.

   cd <INSTALL_DIR>\openvino_2020.3.194\deployment_tools\bin

   Run setupvars.bat

2.Navigate to the face recognition demo folder

cd <INSTALL_DIR>\openvino_2020.3.194\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\demos\python_demos\face_recognition_demo

Run pip install -r requirement.txt

3. Run the demo
   python./face_recognition_demo.py -m_fd "<INSTALL_DIR>\openvino_2020.3.194\deployment_tools\tools
   model_downloader\intel\face-detection-retails-0004\FP16\face-detection-retail-0004.xml" -m_lm "<INSTALL_DIR>\openvino_2020.3.194\deployment_tools\tools
   model_downloader\intel\landmarks-regression-retail-0009\FP16\landmarks-regression-retail-0009.xml" -m_reid "<INSTALL_DIR>\openvino_2020.3.194\deployment_tools\tools
   model_downloader\intel\face-reidentification-retail-0095\FP16\face-reidentification-retail-0095.xml" -i 0 -fg "<IMAGE_DIR>\Pictures\image_name"

Check out the [Interactive Face Recognition Demo](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2020.3/_demos_python_demos_face_recognition_demo_README.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: I followed this steps but now I git this errro: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\demos\python_demos\face_recognition_demo\face_recognition_demo.py", line 24, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable.

Answer (score 0):

so yeah I followed these steps

1. Setup OpenVINO environment.

   `cd <INSTALL_DIR>\openvino_2020.3.194\deployment_tools\bin`

   `setupvars.bat`

result:
[runnigsetupvars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6HeN.png)
so I always get this warning about the libmmd.dll, again I researched for a solution, but I  couldn't find the source of this problem.

2.Navigate to the face recognition demo folder

```
cd <INSTALL_DIR>\openvino_2020.3.194\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\demos\python_demos\face_recognition_demo
    
`pip install -r requirements.txt`
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8mg0.png)
and finally[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72MHf.png)
now I get this error, although OpenCV-python is downloaded, I tried to follow this solution I found:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
opencv-contrib-python
```

but the same cv2 error is showing

Answer (score 0):

Could you please reinstall the OpenVINO 2020.3 and run the verification script successfully. Then, follow again steps from the previous reply since I have validated this on my side and everything works fine. Make sure you restart your computer after the installation of OpenVINO and Microsoft Visual Studio.